# MVC Razor Html Helpers - How to get and set jQuery parameters?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know how to get CampaignPointsId from the DropDownList and set the Label with the return value from the $.getJSON( ... ) function.

**Razor + jQuery:**

```js
@Html.DropDownList("CampaignPointsId", null, new { onchange = "SaveCampaignPoints();" })
    @Html.Label("CampaignPoints", "CampaignPoints: ");
    
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SaveCampaignPoints()
        {
            var url = "/AbilitySets/SaveCampaignPoints";
            
            //selectedId = CampaignPointsId;
  
            $.getJSON(url, { campaignPoints: selectedId }, function(data) { $("#points").html(data.points); });

            // if(points!=null){
            // CampaignPoints = points;}
        }
</script>
​
```

Comment: CampaignPointsId is a drop down, therefore, it will create a `<select />` html element with id CampaignPointsId (e.g. `<select id="CampaignPointsId">...</select>`). All you have to do now is how to get value of a `<select />` element. A quick google will give you the answer.

Comment: `selectedId = $('#CampaignPointsId).val();` but you would be better of removing the `onchange` attribute and using unobtrusive javascript - `$('#CampaignPointsId').change(function() { $.getJSON(url, { campaignPoints: $(this).val() }, ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model,

```
public class MyModel
    {
//some properties...
[NotMapped]
        public SelectList Items{ get; set; }
}
```

In controller, fill the model with Items list

in view,

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Items", Model.Items, "--Select--", new { @id="drpItems"}) 




$(document).ready(function () {

$("#drpItems").change(function () {
        var selectedID = $("#drpItems").val();
//code
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.DropDownList("CampaignPointsId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CampaignPoints, new { onchange = "SaveCampaignPoints(); " })
        @Html.Label("CampaignPoints", "CampaignPoints: ")

```
    function SaveCampaignPoints() {
        var CampaignPointsId = $('#CampaignPointsId').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/AbilitySets/SaveCampaignPoints",
            data: { campaignPoints: CampaignPointsId },
            success: function (points) {
                alert(points);
                },
            error: function (points) { alert("error"); alert(points); },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    }
```